# Showing color of code next to line number

Tags: phpstorm

My computer crashed and I had to reinstall everything, like PhpStorm.

Everything works fine, but I can't get PhpStorm to pre-render the color-code next to my line number, which used to work before.

Show CSS color preview icon in gutter is checked.

[image]

Comment: IDE version etc? Some "proofs" (screenshot) that it still does not show it in simple `.css` file. That `Show CSS color preview icon in gutter` option is the one that does it. Have you tried restarting the IDE? What about trying `File | Invalidate caches...`?

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry for late reply, was having lunch. I've tried invalidate caches but nothing changed. My IDE version is also the latest (if you mean the latest update).

Comment: So .. what language this is? It's not plain CSS. Is it Sass/SCSS .. or something else?

Comment: @LazyOne It's scss

Comment: Seems to work OK here: http://postimg.org/image/dhm4uezgp/ . Can you please try in brand new project with some simple code -- see if it will work there. Using PhpStorm 2017.1 on Windows 10 here.

Comment: @LazyOne opened a new project and created a .css file, but still no color. I also am using PhpStorm 2017.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Well ... in 2016.3 or maybe one of the 2017.1 EAP builds there was issue where this box was not shown because of "wrong" font size (no idea how it was related behind the scene .. but it was). Could you please 1) Try with Default color scheme and Windows as GUI Theme 2) If still the same -- backup and delete IDE-wide settings (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) and start from scratch (do not import anything from previous version/backups) -- any better? Maybe some another option affects this...

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, deleting IDE-wide settings worked. It's quite funny that when I tried to google this problem I found a stackoverflow question with the same question and you helping him too. Back then it was version 2016.1 :D. If you want you can post as answer and I accept it.

Comment: Now you can restore some if not most of your settings back. At very least such stuff as Colors, Keymaps, Code Style, External Tools, Live Templates and more. If you have some free time and desire -- restore other files as well (I'm referring to files from `options` folder) -- restore like 2 at once and see if it still works OK (obviously, such restore individual config file operations  should be done when IDE is closed .. so requires quite a few IDE close/open cycles). P.S. indexes/caches will be rebuilt from scratch so no need to restore them.